# Why do I keep jumping between items when scrolling in reading list?

Tags: ios, reading-list

Why do I keep jumping between items when scrolling when reading an item in reading list on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve also had this problem. Couldn’t figure out why it was sometimes randomly jumping and sometimes not. Maybe I flick the screen in strange ways? I was able to work around it with [this Pythonista script](https://github.com/apiarian/pythonista-ios-scripts/blob/master/reopen-page.py). It reopens the same page in the same tab. Breaks it free from the reading list. So the whole scroll to the end to jump to a different item doesn’t work anymore, but I never really used that, preferring to manually pick the next item.

From the [link:](https://github.com/apiarian/pythonista-ios-scripts/blob/master/reopen-page.py)

```
import appex
import requests
import webbrowser


def main():
    if not appex.is_running_extension():
        url = 'http://arstechnica.com'
    else:
        url = appex.get_url()
    if url:
        webbrowser.get('safari').open(url)
    else:
        print('No input URL found.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll further than the end or beginning of an item in your Reading List, it switches to the next or previous item respectively. This only occurs if you scroll *beyond* the end, but this seems to be what you're doing.

Comment: You would assume that’s all. The problem is that if you flick scroll without reaching the end (or beginning when going up) you Switch list item. Quite annoying!!